# Error: No provider for t

Tags: angular, angular5

I am trying to compile my angular code to production mode via **ng build --prod** and its successful but in browser I get the error :

```
ERROR p {__zone_symbol__error: Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for t!
```

Error: NullInjectorError:…, …}

where as when I run just **ng build** then the html works fine.

I have tried several links mentioned on git hub:

https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19219
https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/6851

Doesn't help much.

Attaching my Package.json file content:

```js
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "angular-cli": {},
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "test": "ng test",
    "pree2e": "webdriver-manager update --standalone false --gecko false",
    "e2e": "protractor",
    "build": "ng build && node server.js",
    "dev": "ng build -w & nodemon server.js --watch dist --watch server",
    "production": "ng build --prod & node server.js dist server "
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "~5.0.0",
    "@jaspero/ng2-alerts": "0.0.7",
    "axios": "^0.17.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.18.2",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "ethereumjs-tx": "^1.3.3",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "mongoose": "^4.12.6",
    "rxjs": "^5.0.1",
    "ts-helpers": "^1.1.1",
    "web3": "^1.0.0-beta.24",
    "web3-provider-engine": "^13.3.3",
    "zone.js": "^0.7.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "1.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.38",
    "@types/node": "^6.0.42",
    "codelyzer": "~2.0.0-beta.1",
    "jasmine-core": "2.5.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "2.5.0",
    "karma": "1.2.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "^0.2.1",
    "protractor": "~4.0.13",
    "ts-node": "1.2.1",
    "tslint": "^4.3.0",
    "typescript": "2.4.2"
  }
}
```

also  app.module.ts

```js
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import {FormsModule} from '@angular/forms';
import {HttpClientModule} from '@angular/common/http';
import {BrowserAnimationsModule} from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
import {JasperoAlertsModule} from '@jaspero/ng2-alerts';
// Imports commented out for brevity
import {RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
// Components
import {AppComponent} from './app.component';
import {LoginComponent} from './component/login/login.component';
import {DashboardComponent} from './component/dashboard/dashboard.component';
// Services
import {RecordsService} from './services/records.service';
import {AccountService} from './services/account.service';
import {AuthenticateService} from './services/authenticate.service';
import {FooterComponent} from './component/footer/footer.component';
import {HeaderComponent} from './component/header/header.component';


// Define the routes
const ROUTES = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: 'login',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeaderComponent,
    FooterComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    BrowserAnimationsModule,
    FormsModule,
    JasperoAlertsModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(ROUTES) // Add routes to the app
  ],
  providers: [
    RecordsService,
    AccountService,
    AuthenticateService
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule {
}
```

Comment: The [tag:angularjs] is for angular 1x, use [tag:angular] for angular 2 and later.

Comment: Are there any other services you are using that are not provided in `providers`?

Comment: Yes, it was AlerService from @jaspero/ng2-alerts, its not mentioned in their docs.
Adding it made it work. Thanks Mate.
You can add your answer.

Comment: @PriyankGupta how do you check what provider wasn't added? I mean I have a big app, so its difficult to check everything. Do you have any hints, how to do this?

Comment: when you compile the project without compression and hashing, instead of t you will the actual module.

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You are trying to use a service that is not listed in `providers` of your AppModule. Add the service to a providers list to make it work.

Answer (score 36):

Run the following command and first find which service dependency is missing. 
Fix it locally, Prod build will automatically works.

`ng serve --prod --optimization=false`

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for.. In production it is difficult to recon what is it wrong.  Thanks :)

Comment: Thank you, thank you, the perfect answer for my situation!

Answer (score 15):

Disable the terser plugin by editing the file:

`node_modules/@angular-devkit/build-angular/src/angular-cli-files/models/webpack-configs/common.js`

and comment out:

```
extraMinimizers.push(new TerserPlugin({
  sourceMap: scriptsSourceMap,
  parallel: true,
  cache: true,
  terserOptions,
}));
```

rebuild the app with `ng build frontend --prod` and you should be able to see in the console which service can't be injected.

Comment: This is absolutely great. I cannot understand why this is not a standard option/flag for testing missing modules in angular or ionic.

Comment: There is a flag: --optimization=false

Answer (score 3):

Your trying to access Service but not provides in your Module

Answer (score 3):

One of my teammate faced this. He was missing `HttpClientModule` in `imports` in `app.module.ts`

Answer (score 2):

if you use **HttpClient** import **HttpClientModule** in your `app.module`

```
  .
  .
  .
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule  // <--- add this line
  ],
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing **import** issues in module file,
Run this code


 `ng serve --configuration=staging --optimization=false` 
OR

 `ng serve --configuration=prod--optimization=false` 

This code will help you to find which **module** is not imported in **Module** file. 
In my case I missed importing **MatSnackBarModule** and **BrowserModule**

Answer (score 0):

I did not want to give up the optimization as the bundle size became about 8 times larger.

luckily it turned out to be something stupid :) I had providers:[]  section in one of my components When I removed it the error has disappeared.

Hope this might be helpful for someone!

Answer (score 0):

For Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for t! (note: only for the error the provider is "t", if it is another provider it may be for not having declared app.module -> provider [])

The problem occurred when I compiled with ng "ng build --prod", switched to "npm run build --prod" and the problem disappeared.

try to compile with another version or with npm

Answer (score 0):

I had this "Error: NullInjectorError: No provider for t!" problem because I used FormBuilder before importing ReactiveFormsModule in app.module

Answer (score 0):

For me, I got this error when building a Chrome Extension with Angular.

The problem: ngIf= instead of *ngIf=.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

In my case, It was throwing exception when I try to call specific page, So I following steps

1. Compared with other page where I was not getting exception,
2. Checked the constructor I was injecting one provider which was not compatible with current updated angular application
3. Removed that and it start working for me.

Answer (score 0):

For me it was:

Error: NG0201: No provider for Xo found in NodeInjector

i was working on some older project and added formControl="..." property inside html <input ...> without adding ReactiveFormsModule in app.module.ts to properly use Reactive Forms.

Adding ReactiveFormsModule to app.module.ts in imports array resolved the issue.